# How to remove a module in angular project?

Tags: angular

I created a module under ClientApp folder. How can I go and delete the module folder? Do I have to modify any other locations for it to work fine? (Angular 5)

Comment: If the module you've created is linked in the AppModule, then you'll have to remove that linking.

Comment: How can I do that? "Remove the linking". There is no track of the deleted module in app.module.ts.

Comment: Nice checklist here:  [How to Delete Component, Service, Module from Angular](http://www.techtutorhub.com/article/How-to-Delete-Component-Service-Module-from-Angular/40)

Answer (score 3):

If you already imported your module in your app module then remove import and remove Class name from declaration. You can delete your folder or files if you does not want it. Make sure that you removed all those links related this module like from : AppModule, RouterModule e.t.c

Comment: I have done the deletion of the folder. But when I try to add a component under the components folder I get this:  Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.
More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.

Comment: first clean your npm cache and rebuild the solution. after that you can add new files

Comment: Still not working. I need a way to completely delete the trace of the module I have deleted from everywhere.

Comment: please try ng generate component [YourComponentName] in cmd and can you show me your error?

Comment: ng g c components\sidenav2 --dry-run --no-spec
Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.
More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.

Comment: Specify the module using the --module parameter. For example, if the main module is app.module.ts, run this:

ng g c component-name --module app